# How to add more filters to google places autocomplete types

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places

I want to add more types to my Google Places autocomplete request. Currently I'm allowing cities in the US, but I want to allow cities and counties. Is counties possible?

Here is what I have.

```
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }
};
```

Comment: Look at supported types here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types autocomplete types are right at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if counties is available.

This is what I pulled from the reference docs for types:

> The types of predictions to be returned. Four
>   types are supported: 'establishment' for businesses, 'geocode' for
>   addresses, '(regions)' for administrative regions and '(cities)' for
>   localities. If nothing is specified, all types are returned. In
>   general only a single type is allowed. The exception is that you can
>   safely mix the 'geocode' and 'establishment' types, but note that this
>   will have the same effect as specifying no types.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompletePrediction)